# Meteor data subscription error when used inside Svelte onMount callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, svelte

I'm building a Meteor/Svelte SPA implementing SSR.

To track changes to Meteor data and keep Svelte reactivity, i'm using the 'meteor/rdb:svelte-meteor-data' package (https://github.com/rdb/svelte-meteor-data).

I'm using the 'svelte-routing' package (https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) to build out my SPA routes.

When using Svelte's onMount lifecycle function to subscribe to a Meteor collection (see below), I get an error thrown at rdb:svelte-meteor-data/subscribe.js:59 (https://github.com/rdb/svelte-meteor-data/blob/master/subscribe.js) which is a push function. This fails because current_component.$$.on_destroy is null and not an array.

**This error only appears when navigating to the component via the Link 'svelte-routing' component. When the component is loaded directly, it loads without error and as expected.**

After further investigation, it looks like current_component is not the component the subscribe method is called from, but the Link component from 'svelte-routing'. When loading the component directly, as mentioned above, it works, but the current_component is the Route component from 'svelte-routing' and still not the correct component.

It looks like for whatever reason, the Link component has not set the on_destroy property to an array, which causes this error when the subscribe function attempts to add a function.

**But the real issue is why are the Link or Route components set as the current component when we are subscribing from inside the onMount function inside a component?**

Notes:

If I wrap the subscribe function in setTimeout the component loads as expected.

If I log current_component directly in the component (see below) it logs the correct component.

```
<script>
  // svelte component rendered by svelte-routing
  import { current_component } from 'svelte/internal';
  import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { useTracker } from 'meteor/rdb:svelte-meteor-data';
  import Artwork from '../../models/Artwork';
  
  export let _id;

  onMount(() => {
    // svelte-routing Link component logged
    // subscribe fails as Link.$$.on_destroy is null
    console.log(current_component);
    Meteor.subscribe('artwork', _id)
  });

  $: artwork = useTracker(() => Artwork.findOne({_id}));

  // correct component logged
  console.log(current_component);
</script>
```

Comment: a function returned by `onMount` is the`onDestroy` for the component - tried to return one with also an unsubscribe call to the Meteor store? e.g. `const mstore = Meteor.subscribe('artwork', _id);
return () => { mstore.stop(); }`

Comment: Hello @foobored. Thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but the same error cropped up. I think thats because the issue lies not with unsubscribing, but with the subscribe function. My assumption is svelte-routing is messing with the current component so when rdb:svelte-meteor-data goes to subscribe, its not adding the subscription to the correct component.

Comment: If you can't find a fix you may ask in the [meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/) and link to this question.